# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'manage.py' IN PYTHON/DJANGO

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I have used below code in a thread running background.

```
os.chdir("MEDIA/" + str(email) + "/" + str(id) + "/")
os.system("rscript DataSet.R " + str(filename) + " >>logfile.log")
os.chdir(settings.BASE_DIR)
```

This Error comes sometimes whenever I run my server. I have no clue whats the issue here. Most of the time the code works. I have to use chdir to run my R scripts.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\MEXSON~1\Desktop\PROJEC~1\TOX2020\MAINWE~1\TOX202~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\MEXSON~1\Desktop\PROJEC~1\TOX2020\MAINWE~1\TOX202~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\MEXSON~1\Desktop\PROJEC~1\TOX2020\MAINWE~1\TOX202~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\MEXSON~1\Desktop\PROJEC~1\TOX2020\MAINWE~1\TOX202~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 62, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\MEXSON~1\Desktop\PROJEC~1\TOX2020\MAINWE~1\TOX202~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\MEXSON~1\Desktop\PROJEC~1\TOX2020\MAINWE~1\TOX202~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 101, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\MEXSON~1\Desktop\PROJEC~1\TOX2020\MAINWE~1\TOX202~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
  File "C:\Users\MEXSON~1\Desktop\PROJEC~1\TOX2020\MAINWE~1\TOX202~1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 332, in main
    reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MEXSON~1\Desktop\PROJEC~1\TOX2020\MAINWE~1\TOX202~1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 298, in python_reloader
    reloader_thread()
  File "C:\Users\MEXSON~1\Desktop\PROJEC~1\TOX2020\MAINWE~1\TOX202~1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 276, in reloader_thread
    change = fn()
  File "C:\Users\MEXSON~1\Desktop\PROJEC~1\TOX2020\MAINWE~1\TOX202~1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 206, in code_changed
    stat = os.stat(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'manage.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the below code from your script and it will perfectly workfine.
os.chdir(settings.BASE_DIR)

Or else,
Move your codes into a different script, and then import that script file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You use 'runserver' to launch Django. It has an "autoreload" function that detects code changes and then restarts itself.

Since you change the directory of the process, Django is no longer in the project root, so the list of files it generates in `django.utils.autoreload.gen_files` does not compute.

The simple fix is to use `subprocess` and fork, then change directory in the child.